# Using a component inside of a Vuetify data table

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a Nuxt `2.9.0` app where I'm using `@nuxtjs/vuetify` `1.11.3`.

I'm refactoring some HTML tables that we have in the app and replacing them with Vuetify's `v-data-table` components. Now, in our old tables we had these bar chart components that we would render inside the table cells, like this:

```html
<th>
  {{ totalAvg }}
  <RatingBar :color="ratingColor(totalAvg)" />
</th>
```

That `RatingBar` component is basically just an empty div with a background color, as you can see below

[image]

What's the proper way in which I can keep this functionality when moving onto the Vuetify data tables?

I know that Vuetify implements some slots, for example the `#header` slot, but I'm not sure exactly how the slots work when it comes to table cells, since the `#header` slot, for example, seems to just append whatever `<template>` you write down for the slot, instead of actually replacing the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuetify's `v-data-table` supports custom rendering for a specific column thru `#item.<name>`. [Link to API doc.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#item.%3Cname%3E)